# Invalid Cross reference ID

Tags: data-loader

I have a csv to update the 35 user profile id. Csv has just two column Id and new profile Id.
I updated the user with ID. I worked for 14 users sucessfully and for other 20 it is throwing Invalid cross reference ID.

All the 35 user have the same profile and all User ID are of 15 digit.I have checked for each of 20 user thier 15 digits exist in org. Users are there in Org having the same ID as in CSV.
Why is it throwing Invalid Cross referecnce.

Please help. thanks.

Comment: What happens whey you try to manually assign the problem users the required profile id?

Comment: I am able to do that. Infact, I copy the USer id in URL from CSV,get the user and update the profile. There is not problem with Profile ID. I tried to update other fields with CSV and it got failed for those 20 user. It seems there is osme problem with User ID. But then How come I am able to open user page with same ID in CSV. Please suggest and help

Comment: This is something weird, I updated 20 records manually, generated a report last by me and got ID. then I copied the ID in CSV. They are exactly same as previous but this time it updated all the records. Strange ..really very strange..

Comment: Are you trying to assign a user license type, like an external community or portal license profile of some sort to your internal users?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be abandoned.

Answer (score 1):

Did you copy paste any of the id  into the csv?

Export all the requires user ids using dataloader and try the update.
It worked for me when i tried.